# Name and notation of the sum of cardinalities of finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Given a finite set $S = \{s_1, s_2, ..., s_n\}$, where each $s_i$ is a finite set of $|s_i|$ elements, let

$$
N = \sum_{s \in S}{|s|}
$$

Is there a canonical name and notation for $N$?

On a superficial level, the Manhattan norm $\|S\|_1$ denotes what I want.
However, this seems like an abuse of the notation, as it refers to absolute values, not sizes of sets.

Comment: Just a comment on the notation: if I understood well the question, then I think the sum is better written as $\sum_{i=1\dots n} |s_i|$. Am I right?

Comment: Your notation for "the sum of cardinal(itie)s", which is the only "name" I know of for them, is basically the standard; we add cardinals with $\sum$.

Comment: @Gabrielek The sum is not better written as $\sum_{i=1\dots n} |s_i|$. Actually $\sum_{s\in S} |s|$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n| s_i|$ are more common, but the three are correct, none of it is better than the others.

Answer (score 0):

We could define disjoint union of $S$ as follows:

$$
\biguplus S=\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{i\}\times s_i.
$$

Then $\left|\biguplus S\right|=\sum_{s\in S}|s|$. Also you can use $\sum$ instead of $\biguplus$, i.e., $\left|\sum S\right|=\sum_{s\in S}|s|$.